# using comment on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm creating a webpage using wordpress. I wanna insert some element in the form as hidden but the comment tag is not working. the wordpress is putting the comment tag within a 'p' tag.I used all methods of commenting.It is not working.

Can anyone tell me how to insert comments in a webpage using wordpress?

thanks i advance.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are trying to build a form using the add/edit page screen in wp-admin i.e. wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page? If so, you might never succeed in your endeavour, but I would give it a try using tinymce-advanced plugin, as you can turn a lot of the filtering of your source code off, and this might solve the problem. Try it, if not let me know and I will tell you how to manually add functionality to stop Wordpress from messing with html code in wp-admin text editor.

Comment: I'm not able to use it. Can u tell me the manual way? Thank you

Comment: Why are you unable to use a plugin? I said if it didn't work I would tell you the manual way, but it is a lot of work, for you and for me, when Tinymce would probably do it in 2 clicks. I have never known a Wordpress user who can change code but not use a plugin.